# JavaScript Regular expression replace except first and last

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regular expression in JavaScript . So string can be replaced but except first and last one.

e.g.

```
str="'Marys' Home'"
```

I want  regular expression in JavaScript so output can be :

```
"'Marys\' Home'"
```

i.e except first and last one single quote `'` replaced by `\'`.

Similar solution  in Python I found: [Regular expression replace except first and last characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139471/regular-expression-replace-except-first-and-last-characters)

Comment: What RegEx did you try? Post yo' code, bud.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can use this:

```
var str = "'Marys' Home'";

var result = str.replace(/(?!^)(')(?!$)/g, '\\$1');
//=> 'Marys\' Home'
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hP9eT0/2)

Comment: your solution works but it fails when there is consecutive `'` quotes. see http://regex101.com/r/hP9eT0/3

Comment: @AvinashRaj: [Actually it works with consecutive quotes also](http://regex101.com/r/hP9eT0/4)

Comment: Yes I had realized right after posting first regex and updated the regex with lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "'Marys' Home'"

function replace(str, pattern, replacement) {

  var firstIndex = str.indexOf(pattern)
    , lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(pattern)
    , re = new RegExp(pattern, 'g')

  if (firstIndex < lastIndex) 
    str = str.substr(firstIndex + pattern.length, lastIndex)

  return str.replace(re, replacement)
}

console.log(replace(str, "'", "\'"))
```

Something like this you are looking for?