# RegExp replace all letter but not first and last

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have to replace all letters of name on ****. 
Example:

Jeniffer -> J****r

I try `$(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/([^\w])\//g, "*"))`

Also, if name is Ron -> R****n

Comment: If you don't care about the number of letters and you always want to replace middle chars with four `*`, why do you want to use a regexp?

Comment: (My bad, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143669/javascript-regular-expression-replace-except-first-and-last) isn't a good dupetarget for this one.)

Comment: Without any more details, it seems [`.replace(/(?!^)\w(?!$)/g, "*")`](https://regex101.com/r/hdx3J4/1) will do.

Comment: `'Jeniffer'.replace(/^(\w).*(\w)$/, '$1****$2')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - OP wants exactly four `*`, regardless of name length. (At least, that's how I read "Jeniffer -> J****r" and "Ron -> R****n".)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know these questions, appetite comes with the eating, the next  question would be "how to make sure the number of `*` is the same as the number of chars removed".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** use a regular expression for this, by capturing the first and last letters in a capture group and ignoring all letters between them, then using the capture groups in the replacement:

```
var updated = name.replace(/^(.).*(.)$/, "$1****$2");
```

Live Example:

```js
function obscure(name) {
  return name.replace(/^(.).*(.)$/, "$1****$2");
}
function test(name) {
  console.log(name, "=>", obscure(name));
}
test("Ron");
test("Jeniffer");
```

But it's perhaps easier without:

```
var updated = name[0] + "****" + name[name.length - 1];
```

Live Example:

```js
function obscure(name) {
  return name[0] + "****" + name[name.length - 1];;
}
function test(name) {
  console.log(name, "=>", obscure(name));
}
test("Ron");
test("Jeniffer");
```

Both of those do assume the names will be at least two characters long. [**I pity the fool**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwM9rL_OsDM) who tries this on Mr. T's surname.

Answer (score 2):

Since, you need to have four asterisk on each condition, you can create a reusable function that will create this format for you:

```js
function replace(str){
  var firstChar = str.charAt(0);
  var lastChar = str.charAt(str.length-1);
  return firstChar + '****' + lastChar;
}
var str = 'Jeniffer';
console.log(replace(str));
str = 'America';
console.log(replace(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears that you're looking for regex lookaround

Regex: `(?<=\w)(\w+)(?=\w)` - group 1 matches all characters which *follow* one character and *followed by* another one.

Tests: https://regex101.com/r/PPeEqx/2/

More Info: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

Find first and last chars and append `****` to the first one and add the last one:

```
const firstName = 'Jeniffer';

const result = firstName.match(/^.|.$/gi).reduce((s, c, i) => `${s}${!i ? `${c}****` : c }`, '');

console.log(result);
```